# Link Dropzone.js with springboot and JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, dropzone.js

i'm working with Spring Boot and Hibernate and this is my code for uploading a form that contains some input from the user and uploading some pictures.
Everything works fine, but now i'm trying to use DropZone.js for more elegant look.

As you can see in the jsp file i'm sending the form content to a specified controller using a model attribute called 'albumCreation', which is actually a class
containing variables, where i store the inputs and uploaded pictures using path attribute.

But now using Dropzone.js, how can i link it to my model attribute ? If not possible any suggestions to do this in a different way ?

**album-creation-Form.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Add Album</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/dropzone.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form:form method ="POST" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="uploadDropzone" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Albums/UploadPictures" modelAttribute="AlbumCreation">

        Title:
        <form:errors path="title"/>
        <form:input path="title"/><br><br>

        Description:
        <form:errors path="description"/>
        <form:textarea path="description"/><br><br>

        Upload pictures:
        <form:errors path="pictures"/>
        <div id="pictures" class="dz-default dz-message">
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
        <!-- This is how i do it without Dropzone.js
            <form:input path="pictures" type="file" name="pictures" accept="image/*" multiple="true" required="true"/><br><br>
        -->

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form:form>


<script src="/static/js/dropzone.js"></script>

<script>

    Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone = {

            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple : true,
            addRemoveLinks : true,
            dictRemoveFile : "Remove Picture",
            acceptedFiles : "image/*"
    };

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

**AlbumManagementController.java**

```
@PostMapping("/UploadPictures")
    public String uploadPictures(@Valid @ModelAttribute("AlbumCreation")AlbumForm theAlbum, BindingResult theBindingResult) throws Exception {

        if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info(">>>>Error creating Album: "+theAlbum.getTitle());
            return "redirect:center";
        }
        else {
            albumService.uploadPicturesFromForm(theAlbum);
            logger.info("Successfully created Album: " + theAlbum.getTitle());
            return "redirect:center";
        }
    }
```

**AlumForm.java**

```
package com.moroccangeek.schoolmanagement.forms;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class AlbumForm {

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min=1,message="is required")
    private String title;

    @NotNull(message = "is required")
    @Size(min=1,message="is required")
    private String description;

    private MultipartFile[] pictures;

    /*
     * no-args constructor
     */
    public AlbumForm() {
        super();
    }

    /*
     * Getters & Setters
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public MultipartFile[] getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }

    public void setPictures(MultipartFile[] pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }

}
```

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: @rajeshkakawat that's irrelevant to my problem, but thank you anyway